# Convert db data encoding to UTF-8

Tags: iphone, sql

I use Sql Server 2000 and I inserted some data in hebrew to a table.
I need to access this data through an iPhone app using an ASP page that query the table.
The problem is that in the iPhone app the Hebrew is shown as strange signs.
I think my problem is that the data that is generated from my db isn't in UTF-8 but in USC-2
Any suggestions how to convert the data from my db to utf so it will be readable on the iPhone?

10x.

Comment: Are you really using ASP or did you mean ASP.NET? Using old-style ASP seems like a strange choice these days.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correctly you have a page that query DB and show data to iPhone. did you try to open that page in desktop browser? what was result? most probably error is that encoding in header is different from actual encoding.

Comment: Yes, the hebrew is represented in strange signs, I know it's an encoding issue and I tried several solutions like setting the CodePage and Charset of the page with no luck..... the other solution I'm looking for is getting the data from the db as utf-8 is it possible?

Comment: i don't think so. but you can recode the data in asp. is it asp.net?